# How to select manually choices with django-multiselectfield without using django froms

Tags: python, django, multi-select

I'm using django-multiselectfield like that :

```
#models.py
weekdays = MultiSelectField(choices=DAYS_OF_WEEK_CHOICES, max_length=11, null=True, blank=False)
```

my question it's possible to select or deselect manually the choices from the DB wihtout using django forms ? 
By using something like that or else in views.py:

```
obj = something.objects.get(id=5)
obj.weekdays.set("Sunday")
obj.save()
```

Comment: Of course it can set in the same way you use charfield .

Comment: obj.weekdays = "Sunday" and don't forget obj.save()

Comment: @Abstonemonsieurbref Thanks for the detailed explanation and the example, it works well now